# Is there a getline(istream, string, delim) that appends to string?

Tags: c++, boost, std

This would be great to avoid copying. Is there anything in std or boost to do this?

Comment: You want to avoid copying *and* you want to append to another string?  How does that work?

Comment: I'm reading from an istream and I need to run some logic between delimiters. Instead of keeping an external buffer and using a getline on a temp buffer and then copying the temp buffer to the external buffer, I'd rather just append to the external buffer.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That seems entirely reasonable.  If you're not averse to using stringstreams, you might find a solution embedded somewhere in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there were no existing solutions, this is what I came up with:

```
istream& appendline(istream& is, string& str, char delim = '\n')
{
    size_t size = str.size();
    size_t capacity = str.capacity();
    streamsize spaceRemaining = capacity - size;

    if (spaceRemaining == 0)
    {
        capacity = max(static_cast<size_t>(8), capacity * 2);
        spaceRemaining = capacity - size;
    }

    // give getline access to all of capacity
    str.resize(capacity);

    // get until delim or spaceRemaining is filled
    is.getline(&str[size], spaceRemaining, delim);

    // gcount includes the delimiter but not the null terminator
    size_t newSize = size + is.gcount();

    // is failbit set?
    if (!is)
    {
        // if string ran out of space, expand and retry
        if (is.gcount()+1 == spaceRemaining)
        {
            is.clear();
            str.resize(newSize);
            str.reserve(capacity * 2);
            return appendline(is, str, delim);
        }
    }
    else if (!is.eof())
        --newSize;

    // resize string to fit its contents
    str.resize(newSize);
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string mystring = "HELLO "; //initial string
int len = mystring.size(); //get initial length
mystring.resize(100); //resize so it's big enough
char* buffer = &mystring[len-1]+1; //get pointer to "spare" space
std::cin.get(buffer , 100-len, '\n'); //read into buffer, until newline
mystring.resize(len + std::cin.gcount()); //shrink to correct size
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this *member* function instead ([doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)):

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

to read data, and  then append that data to a string.

For example, you can wrap this functionality in your own defined function  as:

```
std::istream & getline(std::istream &in, std::string & str, char delim)
{
    char buf[1024];
    in.getline(buf, 1024, delim);
    str.append(buf, in.gcount());
    return in;
}

std::string s = "initial string";

getline(std::cin, s, '\n'); //should append to s
```

Comment: Hmm, do you mean pass the string in as the char* like `&buffer.back()`? I think that would work fine but isn't it technically incorrect, i.e. if the string implementation wasn't contiguous? It also won't automatically allocate new space in the string, but I can tolerate that. Something like `istream.getline(&buffer.back(), buffer.capacity()-buffer.length(), delim)`?

Comment: @MattChambers: I gave an example. See it now.

Comment: OK that's definitely not what I'm after. I want to avoid copying!

Comment: Your example copies from buf to str. I want to read directly into str. Actually, it's copying from the istream buffer to the string, but one copy is better than two. :)

Comment: @MattChambers: Do you know the size of input already? If no, then how would you know much memory you need to store the entire input? At any case, you cannot avoid copying data.

Comment: It's just a buffer for reading an XML tag. So I pick a reasonable size to start with and expand it if necessary. Don't you agree copying once in the general case is better than always copying twice?

Comment: @MattChambers: Copying once and copying twice? What are you taking about? Which method copy once and which twice?

Comment: In your example, getline copies from the istream buffer to buf. Then from buf to str. If you pass the string itself to getline, it copies only from the istream buffer to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the global std::getline instead of the member method

```
stringstream s;
s << "line1\nline2";
string str;
while(std::getline(s, str)) cout << str;
```

output: line1line2